# "The method 'setEventHandler' isn't defined for the type 'RtcEngine'." and also, "The named parameter 'joinChannelSuccess' isn't defined."

Tags: android, flutter, dart

need some help. I'm following this tutorial where the guy is using Agora to build a video streaming app with flutter. I'm using the same functions, but I'm getting some errors
this is my code

```
Future<void> initializeAgora() async {

    List<int> _users = [];

    RtcEngineContext context = RtcEngineContext(appId: appId);
    _engine = await createAgoraRtcEngine();
    await _engine.initialize(context);

    _client = await AgoraRtmClient.createInstance(appId);

    await _engine.enableVideo();
    await _engine.setChannelProfile(ChannelProfileType.channelProfileLiveBroadcasting);
    await _engine.setClientRole(role: ClientRoleType.clientRoleBroadcaster);

    _engine.setEventHandler(
      RtcEngineEventHandler(
        joinChannelSuccess: (channel, uid, elapsed)
      )
    );

  }
```

My pubsec.yaml file contains the following:

```
    dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  agora_rtc_engine: ^6.1.0
  agora_rtm: ^1.5.0
  flutter_riverpod: ^2.3.4
  shared_preferences: ^2.1.0
  app_popup_menu: ^1.0.0
  modal_bottom_sheet: ^2.1.2
  circular_menu: ^2.0.1
```

Comment: To get a relevant answer, you should provide more information about the error you are getting, including any details provided in the log or stack trace.